# cloak attribute for riotjs to prevent raw html

Tags: angularjs, web-frameworks, riot.js

sometimes the value of the object is displayed correctly, but sometimes [object] is displayed, this is resolved when pressing F5, to that's why I think that data isn't loaded when html is ready. In Angular there is cloak to prevent raw html to show up. Anything similar in riotjs?

Comment: could you provide a code example?

Comment: `<div each="{!item.storageLocation.subLocation && item.storageLocation ? [true] : []}" class="attribute-field" >{__('procedureDetail.table.location')}<span>{item.storageLocation}</span></div>`

Comment: I think that you are not using the each method correctly, because you are using it to iterate over an array that only has the true value. It´s used like this , you iterate and you can access the object properties that you are iterating  <div each="{[{key:'a'},{key:'b'}]}">
    {key}
  </div>

Comment: I use this method to simulate and if condition because there is a bug in if if you have more then 1 condition

Comment: I´m not aware of that bug. Here is an example with multiple condition: http://plnkr.co/edit/6QzOwo3H3chA1t9RvFVA?p=preview . Try to create a plunker with your issue, so it´s easy to find the problem.